# How to compute the sequence $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{-\frac{n^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ in closed form

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\exp(-\frac{n^2}{2\sigma^2})$ in this question comes from discrete Gaussian distribution.

I tried many different ways, but it seems that I could not a closed form solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "closed form".  The sum from $n=0$ to $\infty$ can be expressed using a Jacobi theta function: 
$$ \frac{1 + \theta_3\left(0, e^{-1/(2\sigma^2)}\right)}{2}$$